# insert whole table types in Oracle into database without index

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a new question must to be solved! I had created a table as type

```
TYPE ebRBKTable IS TABLE OF EBTDCCRBK%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
rbkTable        ebRBKTable;
```

and then insert some data into table by following statements

```
rbkTable(InsertTable).BDADDUSERID             := 'FT_RBK_TDCC';
```

the last i do insert with following statement

```
FORALL i IN 1..InsertTable - 1
INSERT INTO EBTDCCRBK VALUES rbaTable(i);
```

I would like to ask whether is there some ways to insert all type once without `count(i)`

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "insert all type once without count(i)"? You don't have "count(i)" in your sample code. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to remove "i" from my insert statement like the following statement "INSERT INTO EBTDCCRBK VALUES rbaTable;" , the current way that database store date one by one, I would like throw a table type in oracle into database's table once and commit once to reduce transaction

Comment: You can't remove the (i), it's needed by the FORALL statement. FORALL sends all the data in one step, and you only COMMIT once after it already.

Comment: Remember, FORALL is *NOT* a FOR loop! :)

Comment: This is not a real question. It doesn't state whether your job is done using the existing code neither what you wish to achieve is rational.

Comment: Thanks for reply, then I think my question will be asked with other way.. my question is I would like to insert a data which type is declared as table of exist table in oracle into database like following statement "INSERT INTO EBTDCCRBK SELECT * FROM rbkTable", but the error " ora-00942 table or view does not exist "shows up ~

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Would you please explain concept of "FORALL is NOT For loop" with your idea, thank you so much!

Comment: It's not my idea, it's simply not a loop. It runs 1 insert statement, it binds the entire array in one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `forall` statement is not a loop as such.

What it does is send ALL elements of the array to the SQL engine in one go, which enables the  SQL to insert the rows without having to go back to the PL/SQL engine to get more data.

In other words `FORALL` removes the context switching that you would have in a regular FOR loop.

We can show this with a simple trace. Consider:

```
SQL> alter session set sql_trace=true;

Session altered.

SQL> declare
  2    TYPE ebRBKTable IS TABLE OF EBTDCCRBK%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  3    rbkTable        ebRBKTable;
  4  begin
  5
  6    for idx in 1..100000
  7    loop
  8      rbkTable(idx).BDADDUSERID := dbms_random.string('a', 10);
  9    end loop;
 10
 11    forall idx in 1..rbkTable.count
 12    insert into EBTDCCRBK values rbkTable(idx);
 13    commit;
 14
 15  end;
 16  /
```

in the SQL trace we see:

```
INSERT INTO EBTDCCRBK
VALUES
 (:B1 )


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.07       0.07          1        724       3066      100000
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        2      0.07       0.07          1        724       3066      100000
```

vs a regluar loop:

```
SQL> alter session set sql_trace=true;

Session altered.

SQL> declare
  2    TYPE ebRBKTable IS TABLE OF EBTDCCRBK%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  3    rbkTable        ebRBKTable;
  4  begin
  5
  6    for idx in 1..100000
  7    loop
  8      rbkTable(idx).BDADDUSERID := dbms_random.string('a', 10);
  9    end loop;
 10
 11    for idx in 1..rbkTable.count
 12    loop
 13      insert into EBTDCCRBK values rbkTable(idx);
 14    end loop;
 15    commit;
 16
 17  end;
 18  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> alter session set sql_trace=false;
```

and the trace file shows:

```
INSERT INTO EBTDCCRBK
VALUES
 (:B1 )


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute 100000      3.33       3.24          1        689     104216      100000
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total   100001      3.33       3.24          1        689     104216      100000
```

notice the trace file in the `FORALL` version only had ONE execute, i.e. the SQL engine did the work in one hit. In the `FOR LOOP` variant, the SQL engine had 100k executes, and used a lot more CPU to do the same job (as it had to do a lot of single operations and the session was context switching from pl/sql->sql for each inserted row.

Comment: may I ask what are those number's unit? is it millisecond or second?

Comment: @Kun-yaoWang the times (cpu/elapsed) are seconds.